# facebook PHP SDK user ID is 0, but JS says user is logged in, page loops forever until F5

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a page tab app that has server-side checks for whether the user is logged in, has given the required permissions and has liked the page. If any of those is not complete, the page contains only the JS required to do what's needed. When everything is done, page is reloaded via `location.reload(true)`, and the server-side checks run again just to be sure, since I need the data on the server-side eventually.

The problem is, for some users, one of which, conveniently, is my colleague, the server-side check for user always fails on these page reloads (both `$fb->getUser()` is 0 and `$fb->api('/me')` throws an exception). The data is all there, user is logged in, has given all permissions, has liked the page, everything is correct, but server-side - can't retrieve user, even though the page is being refreshed. However, if I click cancel on the page refresh dialog (Firefox shows it since `signed_request` is being posted) and manually refresh by clicking F5, everything goes on correctly.

What could cause this and how to fix it?

App: [https://www.facebook.com/dateks.lv/app_744983135526926](https://www.facebook.com/dateks.lv/app%5f744983135526926)

Comment: Can you give the app url? Also, what specific errors are you getting?

Comment: Send the app token back to the server by GET or POST. Facebook SDK use cookies or request params. Your colleague may have disabled cookies, or using Safari, which has a bug with cookies.

Comment: @Sahil - the specific error in the exception is obvious: "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

Comment: You have to post your auth code you are using in the app, also can you provide the app url

Comment: @Fracsi - but the page is already being reloaded, which should mean the cookies are being sent. My colleague also says the cookies are enabled.

Comment: @SahilMittal - added app URL. What do you mean by "post your auth code you are using in the app"?

Comment: The login code i meant

Comment: What login code? The JS code can be seen by viewing the page source, server-side there is only `$fb->getUser()` and `$fb->api('/me')` in a try/catch block, nothing else that's relevant to the problem.

Comment: You mean shall I see your the page source and check what the problem is? Good luck with your problem, in this way nobody is going to help you out.

Comment: What exactly is your problem with checking the page source?

Comment: Well, good riddance then, I'll wait for someone less stuck-up. I have given all the info that's required. This problem only occurs for a few rare users, for most others (including me) it works perfectly fine from start to finish, so I'm suspecting it has something to do with cookies, but I have no idea what exactly, which is why I'm posting here.

Comment: @Fracsi - when the page reload happens, it sends POST with `signed_request` in it, and in the cookie list there is a cookie named fbsr_appIdHere with signed request data in it, which, from what I understand by reading the SDK code, is used for retrieving the user's ID. Checking server-side, the cookie is there after page reload.